# Jquery ajax doesn't remove previous div style

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have 2 ajax calls and both ajax call using the same div id="result". The first ajax call is display Google maps and the second ajax is retrieve data from my db.

Before any ajax call. The div is

```
<div id="result">
```

Then first call Google maps ajax. The div changed to

```
<div id="result" style="background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden; ">
```

note* - Google maps automatically add attribute above.

After that, call the second ajax. The style attribute doesn't remove.

```
<div id="result" style="background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
```

How can I reset the result div to the default and display the result.

Comment: Are you using `.load()` on `#result` ?

Comment: it's probably not the best idea to adjust what external API does to your page, its code can change over time... just a thought...

Comment: @ZathrusWriter What does it mean, can I have example?

Comment: well, if you use an API, the API will add `style` tag to your div... this style attribute can be subject to various changes as the API evolves, so you can get `style` attribute one day, then a `class` attribute the other day... also, there probably is reason (cross-browser compatibility maybe?) why Google puts their styling on your DIVs... without this, you may discover that your page is broken in some browsers but works in others

Comment: Can you show ajax call ?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter How about if I only adjust the div style other than external API (Google maps). It means when calling Google maps, the style will be add back.

Comment: yes vzhen, adjusting it rather than removing it would be probably a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#result').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to

**reset the style**

```
$("#result").attr("style","");
```

**or even add your new style**

```
$("#result").attr("style",newStyleCode);
```

Comment: I just want to remove, but anyway i learnt new thing from you.